# Error 1001 The specified service does not exist as an installed service

Tags: windows-installer

I am testing a windows installer I have made for one of my applications. I got the following error during uninstallation

Event Type:    Error
Event Source:    MsiInstaller
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    11001
Date:        7/25/2011
Time:        4:36:16 PM
User:
Computer:
Description:
The description for Event ID ( 11001 ) in Source ( MsiInstaller ) cannot be found. The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display messages from a remote computer. You may be able to use the /AUXSOURCE= flag to retrieve this description; see Help and Support for details. The following information is part of the event: Product:  -- Error 1001. Error 1001. An exception occurred while uninstalling. This exception will be ignored and the uninstall will continue. However, the application might not be fully uninstalled after the uninstall is complete. --> The specified service does not exist as an installed service, (NULL), (NULL), (NULL).
Data:
0000: 7b 31 37 43 45 36 35 42   {17CE65B
0008: 32 2d 37 33 34 33 2d 34   2-7343-4
0010: 43 32 38 2d 41 31 45 39   C28-A1E9
0018: 2d 34 31 45 36 39 39 37   -41E6997
0020: 37 46 45 41 44 7d         7FEAD}

the scenario was

1. installed the application using VS 2008 setup project -- it installs a service
2. stopped and deleted the service using 'sc delete servicename.exe' from command prompt
3. tried to uninstall the application from control panel

The RemovePreviousVersions option is True in my case. Is this a proper scenario or is the installer not designed to survive this kind of resilience testing?

Could anyone please guide me on solving this?

Comment: It looks like your service uninstall custom action fails. Try debugging it to see what happens. Perhaps it doesn't handle the case in which your service is missing.

Comment: Thanks Cosmin. I tried catching the exceptions from service installerclass uninstall function. Then I got the exception again from 
System.Configuration.Install.InstallException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified service does not exist as an installed service at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.RemoveService() at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState) at System.Configuration.Install.Installer.Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)

The RemoveService mentioned above seems to be not accessible. Can I ignore this exception somehow?

Comment: Instead of catching exceptions you should avoid them. For example, you should call RemoveService function only if you find the service by using another function.

Comment: @Cosmin Pirvu
RemoveService() seems to be an underlying function inside Uninstall function. So I am not being able to control the call of RemoveService(). I am using the following code
'public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
        {
            try
            {
                base.Uninstall(savedState);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry(this.source, "Service uninstallation failed. Exception: " + ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
            }
        }'
which again throws exception.

Comment: I did a repair of the installer which installed the service back. But sometimes an 'Error:1001 the specified service already exists" comes. In other cases, a further uninstall works fine. Thanks Comsin for the help.